# PHP Validation Class Quickie

Tags: php, class, function

Got a quick question, I'm building a big website for a personal project and I think I'm looking at classes and functions for validation of forms and data etc.

My question I guess is:

Can I use a class to house all the functions that will validate dependant upon the data been passed and if so how can I target certain functions within the class (email addresses, phone numbers etc).

If my logic is right how would it look in code format?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you check how YII does it? it might give you a bit of a trouble while you implement it - but once you have it you'll be able to write yii style rules without problems... and you can then place it all in one class that you can extend for any purpose you need

Comment: I kinda want to learn this on my own and not use you a framework that my site will be dependant upon.

Comment: that's what i meant... open yii source code and see how they did it. i didn't recommend you to implement your site using yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your validating functions statically within a class. Then include this class as and where you need it.

```
class Validator {

    public static function validateEmail($email) {
        // validation logic for email
        // return true or false
    }

    public static function validatePhone($phone) {
        // validation logic for phone
        // return true or false
    }
}

// in a different file, where you want to use this class

require('validator.php');
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (Validator::validateEmail($email)) {
    // valid email
} else {
    // invalid email
}
```

Comment: Thanks - would it be best to only call the validator when needed or would a config.php file that includes all the files slow down the website?

Comment: Since validation is not something that is done too often, I would reccommend including the file only when necessarry.

Answer (score 0):

I created a validation class in PHP to sanitize data and placed it on my [site](http://jdhnet.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/php-validation/). It extends the standard validation functionality which is based on the command filter_var and constants like FILTER_VALIDATE_INT. These functions make it possible to:

- set lower and upper boundaries for integers
- set lower and upper boundaries for floats
- validate Boolean values on different kinds of values
- set lower and upper boundaries for the lengths of strings
- check if a certain value is part of an array
- ....